# Message Input React Component Disable File Upload

Tags: reactjs, getstream-io

Is it possible to disable file uploads in the  component in React? I can't seem to find the property to achieve this and don't feel comfortable just hiding the upload button.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more explicit please ? What do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a prop called `maxNumberOfFiles`, you can set it to zero to disable file/image attachments.

It will disable the button and any logic.

For docs, https://getstream.github.io/stream-chat-react/#messageinputsmall